# Lambda error in code when making form and onload

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, lambda

I get this error:

> IntelliSense: no suitable conversion function from "lambda []void (Form::Form *arg1)->void" to "Form::OnLoad" exists   c:\users\topkek\desktop\project\test\tset\test\main.cpp

Real error:

> Error  8   error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from '`anonymous-namespace'::' to 'Form::OnLoad' c:\users\topkek\desktop\project\test\tset\tes‌​t\main.cpp

This is the code:

```
new Form::Form("TEST_MAIN", "Test main", (Form::OnLoad)[](Form::Form* arg1)->void {
```

form.h:

```
typedef void(*OnLoad)(Form*);
Form(const char* WindowClass, const char* Title, OnLoad Func = NULL);
```

Form.cpp:

```
Form::Form(const char* szWindowClass, const char* Title, OnLoad Func) {
```

Comment: IntelliSense messages are not considered "real" error messages. Can you compile the code and post the "real" error message from the compiler please?

Comment: Error 8 error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from '`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda0>' to 'Form::OnLoad' c:\users\topkek\desktop\project\test\tset\test\main.cpp

Answer (score 0):

```
(Form::OnLoad)[](Form::Form* arg1)->void { /*...*/ })
```

That is one weird lambda :)

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but you don't need a lambda for this:

```
auto f = new Form::Form("TEST_MAIN", "Test main", &Form::OnLoad);
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                                  Address of function
```

If you want a lambda, drop the start:

```
auto f = new Form::Form("TEST_MAIN", "Test main", [](Form::Form* arg1)->void {});
```

Comment: auto f = new Form::Form("TEST_MAIN", "Test main", [](Form::Onload)->void {Form::Form* arg1}); doesnt work                            auto f = new Form::Form("TEST_MAIN", "Test main", &Form::OnLoad); that also doesnt work becouse a type name is not allowed