# Lambda usage gives conversion errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, lambda

I'm using a lambda for a homework assignment. For what I've seen, it is an anonymous, encapsulated function of sorts. I made a small test that simply returns the maximum of two given values like max().

```
double testx, testy = 0.0;
// Give the above some values
double maxi = [testx, testy] () {return (testx > testy ? testx : testy); };
```

In every attempt to compile this lambda, I get build errors. (Code C2440)

> no suitable conversion function from "lambda []double ()->double" to
>   "double" exists

I have attempted more than just this example, each to be made with the error above with the respective return type. There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39932039/lambda-error-in-code-when-making-form-and-onload), that seemed to be given the same error as me on an earlier version of Visual Studio, given an answer of avoiding the lambda for their purposes.

```
double maxi = [testx, testy] () -> double {return (testx > testy ? testx : testy); };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getting this error because you're trying to assign the lambda expression itself to a variable of type double. The compiler error states just that. What you should do is assign the lambda to a variable that can hold it:

```
auto l = [testx, testy] () {return (testx > testy ? testx : testy); };
```

or

```
std::function<double()> l = [testx, testy] () {return (testx > testy ? testx : testy); };
```

and then assign the invocation's result:

```
double res = l();
```

Alternatively, you can immediately invoke the lambda:

```
double maxi = ([testx, testy] () {return (testx > testy ? testx : testy); })();
```

- note the extra parenthesis.

Comment: On the alternative, how do the extra parenthesis add the functionality?

Comment: It's a two-phase action: you first create the lambda object, and then immediately invoke it (you can actually omit the parenthesis wrapping the lambda itself and leave only the last pair, but I think this is a bit clearer). Note that this isn't the common way to use lambdas in C++, and is only shown to present all syntactic options.